# meta-tags being set twice

Tags: ruby, meta-tags

Using the gem 'meta-tags' I am attempting to set both the meta tags for Twitter cards and og:

```
set_meta_tags :twitter => {
    :card => 'summary_large_image',
    :site => 'mysitename',
    :title => 'example',
    :image => {
        :src => "http://example.com/rock.jpg"
    }}


set_meta_tags :og => {
    :site_name => 'mysitename',
    :title => 'example',
    :url => request.original_url,
    :image => [, "http://example.com/rock2.jpg"]",
}
```

Everything gets set correctly however it gets set twice. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When creating the title to a question please don't artificially tack on the keywords for the question, such as "- ruby". If you can incorporate them into the flow of the sentence that's fine but Stack Overflow doesn't use them for searching nor do the search engines, and they just make the question's title awkward to read.

Comment: You have a couple of syntax errors in your code, in the line `:image => [, "http://example.com/rock2.jpg"]",`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define attributes separately for Twitter. As per the documentation:

> if you're already using OpenGraph to describe data on your page, it’s
>   easy to generate a Twitter card without duplicating your tags and
>   data.

This to minimize duplicate markup.

https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags